# MySQL: Growth in Column Value for Given Foreign Key and Specific Date Range

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database that I update every day with the amount of pins on Pinterest for a given URL (page_id).  **How do I write a query that will return the page_id with the largest growth for a given date range?**

Typically, I plan on setting the @StartDate = YESTERDAY and setting the @EndDate = Today, but I'd like the flexibility to adjust the dates within my query.

Here is the current schema of my pins table:

```
mysql> describe pins;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| page_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date    | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pins    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is the desired output of the query I need your help with:

```
mysql> [fancy-mysql-query] ORDER BY Pins_DayOverDay DESC LIMIT 1;

+-------------------+---------------------------+
| page_id           | Pins_DayOverDay           |
+-------------------+---------------------------+
|             12345 |                     12345 |
+-------------------+---------------------------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear whether the "amount of pins" is a daily delta (net change in value), or whether its a cumulative total (the number of pins effective as of the given date.)

Comment: It is the cumulative total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `pins` column is a daily delta, the net change in the number of pins added/removed on a given date, then:

```
SELECT @StartDate = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL -1 DAY
SELECT @EndDate   = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT t.page_id
     , SUM(t.pins) AS `Pins_DayOverDay`
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.date >= @StartDate
   AND t.date <= @EndDate
 GROUP
    BY t.page_id
 ORDER BY `Pins_DayOverDay` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

If the `pins` column is cumulative and contains a total count of the number of effective pins (pins done on previous days plus pins added/removed today), assuming that `(page_id,date)` is unique:

```
SELECT t.page_id
     , (t.pins - s.pins) AS `Pins_DayOverDay`
  FROM mytable t
  JOIN mytable s
    ON s.page_id = t.page_id
 WHERE t.date = @EndDate
   AND s.date = @StartDate
 GROUP
    BY t.page_id
 ORDER BY `Pins_DayOverDay` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

The query above assumes that `(page_id,date)` is unique. If the same page_id can have multiple rows with the same `date`, then we'd need to add aggregate functions. (I will provide that query if you need it.)

Comment: Thanks for the clear response.  The `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` variable statements return null.  Even when I set them manually the query is returning 0's for every page_id.  Here is the query: `SELECT t.page_id, (t.pins - s.pins) AS 'Pins_DayOverDay' FROM pins t JOIN pins s ON s.page_id = t.page_id WHERE t.date = @EndDate AND s.date = @StartDate GROUP BY t.page_id ORDER BY 'Pins_DayOverDay' DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: I think I discovered the problem.  The first 10 pages_ids didn't have any growth yesterday (which is why they returned 0).  When I changed the query to: `... ORDER BY (t.pins - s.pins) ...` it returned the page_ids with the most growth.  It looks like the GROUP BY statement isn't working with the alias name.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @Abundnce10: Your query shows a string literal in the ORDER BY clause.  A reference to a column alias can be enclosed in backticks, but not within single quotes. MySQL sees single quotes as a string literal, not an identifier.